# How did people notice I edited my answer?

Tags: support, edits

I posted an answer a week ago and got several upvotes for it, and it was marked accepted. Today I decided to add something to make it better, so I edited it.  I received 2 more upvotes during the next hour.

How did people notice that I edited my answer?

Answer (score 6):

Questions that have been recently edited or answered can show up in the "Active" tab of the questions list.

See:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active

Answer (score 1):

When anyone posts a new answer, or edits the question or an answer, it gets bumped to the top of the main page.

Answer (score 1):

One you edit any part of the question it ends up at the top of the [active question tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active)

Answer (score 1):

They didn't.

When edited the question re-appear in the main page again.

Somebody read it, and upvote it.

You can tell if the answer was edited because a legend "Edited..." appears in it.